# Async call to WebService segue happens before data comes back

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

**The Background**

I have an iOS application I am building with `StoryBoard` for the UI and `AFNetworking` for the back end. On my `UIViewController` I have some text boxes. When the user hits a submit `UIButton` I am making the AFNetworking call to a web service which returns an XML file.

**The issue**

I used the `StoryBoard` interface to hook up the button to a `UITableViewController`. Initially this worked fine because I had the code for the web service call inside the `UITableViewController`. The problem is that if the web service returns nothing I get a blank `UITableView`. So I moved the web service call into the `UIViewController` to be called when the button is pushed. OOPS! I make the web service call and the `prepareForSegue` gets called before the web service returns the data since its `Asynchronous`.

**My Question**

- What is the best approach when getting data from a web service when you are using storyboards. Should I make the call inside the UITableViewController and then go back to the `UIViewController` if there is no data or an error returned from the service. If so how do I get back. I have tried `self.navigationController popViewController` but it comes up with a warning in the console that removing a view controller can mess up the stack.
- Is there a way that I can control when the segue is called and only do it once I have data back from the web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this step by step answer to help anyone else out that may need help with this:

```
Connect the two ViewControllers in Storyboard which will create a segue.
```

You simply select the first view controller (make sure the viewController is highlighted with a blue line and you didn't select like an image view or navigationItem. Then CTRL and click on the destination view controller (where you want to transition to). [image: connecting two scenes]

The round circle in the middle is called the `segue`. If you click on that and go to your attributes panel on the right, you will see this:[image: your segue attributes panel]

In the identifier enter a name you want to call this transition: for example myNewPage.

Whenever you are ready to make the call to the next scene. Use this delegate method to do pass data from one controller to another or do anything special:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    NameOfDestinationController *dataViewController;
    dataViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"nameOfYourSegueIdentifier"]) {

        dataViewController.variable1 = self.variable1;
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in my case I needed to trigger the segue after I got a success from the AFNetworking web service call. So in the Success block I added this line:

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nameOfYourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

It works perfectly now!!!